# Trying to implement button click sound with MediaPlayer crashes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a custom view (a button) and I want it to have a certain sound when pressed.

```
private void playSound() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        initMediaPlayer();

    try {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getAssets().openFd("music/number_tap.m4a");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call the `playSound` method every time the button is clicked. It works well as long as there is only one button on screen. No problem at all.

It crashes if I have more buttons on the screen and I press the first button a couple of times (works) and then some other button 2 times (crashes on the second press of the second button).

Any idea what could be wrong? Here's the crash stacktrace.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.matejhacin.multiflow, PID: 20991
>                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1163)
>                                                                                 at com.matejhacin.multiflow.views.KeyButtonView.playSound(KeyButtonView.java:126)
>                                                                                 at com.matejhacin.multiflow.views.KeyButtonView.onTouch(KeyButtonView.java:77)

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the logcat?

Comment: Just the IllegalStateException as you can see above.

Comment: Hmm.. nothing obvious jumps out.. are you pausing it somewhere else perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you have your own implementation of that button KeyButtonView.java, and in that class you have mediaPlayer as a member variable, so when you have two buttons, respectively you have two instances of KeyButtonView class and two instances of mediaPlayer. Why don't you use one instance of mediaPlayer, let's say you make it static, and make playSound() and initMediaPlayer() methods synchronized and static, this should be a quick and simple change, just to test if there is the issue. And something else, you use onTouch() to handle a click, why don't you try with OnClickListener? If you do not use onTouch properly you will end with bunch of calls on the UI thread, and each blocking at prepare(), this is not good. Once you fix this issue, you should consider rewrite it with prepareAsync() and setOnPreparedListener().

Comment: Your idea to make MediaPlayer and those methods static worked flawlessly.  Thanks a lot!

The reason I am using onTouch instead of onClick is because I need the button to have effect as soon as it is pressed down, not when it is clicked (pressed and let go). Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: If you are to receive bunch of fast press downs, you should make the response time of the sound as fast as possible, you can optimize your code, by using seekTo() (once the sound is buffered with prepare()), so that way you will not need to buffer with prepare(), each time a button is pressed, but just seek to 0, and the sound will start immediately. From what I see here:

http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif

For short in onResume() you buffer (prepare()), then each press you seekTo(0), and in onPause() you call stop() and release().